# Retrieving the url parameter from a JSON store from a EXTJS ComboBox

Tags: javascript, c#, extjs, combobox, datastore

I am having a problem retrieving the parameters from the URL section of a JSON store for a combobox in EXTJS from my code behind page in C#. The following is the code in the store:

```
var ColorStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoLoad: true,
    url: '/proxies/ReturnJSON.aspx?view=rm_colour_view',
    root: 'Rows',
    fields: ['company', 'raw_mat_col_code', 'raw_mat_col_desc']
});
```

And the following code is in my code behind page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string jSonString = "";
    connectionClass.connClass func = new connectionClass.connClass();
    DataTable dt = func.getDataTable("sELECT * from rm_colour_view");
    //Response.Write(Request.QueryString["view"]);
    string w = Request.Params.Get("url");
    string z = Request.Params.Get("view");
    string x = Request.Params.Get("view=");
    string c = Request.Params.Get("?view");
    string s = Request.QueryString.Get("view");
    string d = Request.Params["?view="];
    string f = Request.Form["ColorStore"];
    jSonString = Serialize(dt);
    Response.Write(jSonString);
}
```

The string `w` has gives the following output:

> /proxies/ReturnJSON.aspx

but, all the others strings return `null`.

How can `rm_colour_view` be retrieved from the datastore?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
string s = Request.QueryString("view")
```